# fitting function for a given data set

Tags: r, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I'm trying to fitting the following function y(x)=a*( 1 + (x^2)/(b^2) )^t to a particular set of data , where, a, b and t are constants that want to determine by fitting.

I try the following, for example

```
len <- 24
x = runif(len)
y = x^3 + runif(len, min = -0.1, max = 0.1)
plot(x, y)
s <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, length = 50)
lines(s, s^3, lty = 2)

df <- data.frame(x, y)
m <- nls(y~a*( 1 + (x^2)/(b^2) )^t, data = df, start = list(a=1,t=0, b=1), trace = T)

> Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
```

Can someone help me to set this function to these points, even if the fitting becomes bad, the important is to get fit this function, ie that she run on the data

thanks everyone

Comment: Change the `start` values.

Comment: This helps but doesn't solve the problem: `m <- nls(y~exp(loga)*( 1 + (x^2)/(b^2) )^t,  data = df, start=list(loga=0,b=0.5,t=2),trace=TRUE, control=nls.control(maxiter=10000,minFactor=1e-8))`.

Comment: Try changing your function to y = (a + b x^2)^t.

Answer (score 0):

Because your data are changing randomly, for some situations the value of *a* is close to zero and your function becomes zero. The curve fit procedure fails at that point.  Randomizing the start parameters might work for some situations.

A slightly more stable output can be computed using the LM algorithm:

```
require("minpack.lm")
LMCurveFit <- function(df) {

  # The function to be fit
  FitFunction <- function(params, x) {
    with (
      as.list(params), {
         a*(1 + x^2/b^2)^t
      }
    )
  }

  # Residual
  Residual <- function(params, x, y) {
    FitFunction(params, x) - y
  }

  # Sum of squares of residuals
  ssqfun <- function(params, x, y) {
    sum(Residual(params, x, y)^2)
  }

  # Normalize the data
  x_max = max(x)
  y_max = max(y)
  df$x = df$x/x_max
  df$y = df$y/y_max

  # Define start parameters
  a_start = 0.1
  b_start = 1.0
  t_start = 1.0
  param_start = c(a = a_start,
                  b = b_start,
                  t = t_start)

  # Do LM fit
  nls.out <- nls.lm(par = param_start,
                    fn = Residual,
                    control = nls.lm.control(nprint=0,
                                             ftol=.Machine$double.eps,
                                             ptol=.Machine$double.eps,
                                             maxfev=10000, maxiter=1024),
                    x = df$x,
                    y = df$y)

  # Revert scaling
  nls.out$par[1] = nls.out$par[1]*y_max
  nls.out$par[2] = nls.out$par[2]*x_max

  # Get the parameters
  params_fit = coef(nls.out)
  print(params_fit)

  # Compute predicted values
  predicted = FitFunction(as.list(params_fit), df$x*x_max)
}

# LM fit
pred_y = LMCurveFit(df)
lines(x, pred_y)
```